# Fifth Element - Mondoshawans in a lift

Tags: story-identification, the-fifth-element

I can picture a scene where Bruce Willis is trying to get through a bunch of Mondoshawans - I think it's in a lift or a large room? He starts rocking one of them side to side and the others fall into step.
He dodges through as the gaps open and close.

Trouble is I can't find the scene on the DVD! Have I got the wrong film or am I just going crazy!?

Hitchhiker's? Dr Who? Help!

Comment: Definitely not on any version of *Fifth Element* I've seen - closest the film gets to a lift is the airlock part of their ship that touches down in Egypt.  Having trouble placing that into any Bruce Willis film honestly.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is the classic "*Goombas in the Elevator*" scene from the runaway hit film [Super Mario Bros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros._(film)). Bob Hoskins (not Bruce Willis) rocks some large lizards from side to side to the soothing elevator music.

You're possibly conflating it with the Mondoshawan's typical way of walking

Comment: +1 for remembering that, because I'm already trying to forget I saw it.

Comment: "runaway hit film" in the sense of "run away from film, hit anyone who tries to stop you"?

Comment: A "runaway hit" so successful, [it ruined the careers of pretty much everyone involved in the movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsGkMSY_Fag).

Comment: @Snowman - All the actors did just fine. None of them seemed to have taken much of an impact. The directors, on the other hand didn't work again for a decade.

Comment: $21 million box office on $48 million budget, 15% on Rotten Tomatoes, 4.0/10 on IMDB.

Comment: @RussellBorogove - Yeah, but when you take into account overseas box-office, rentals, VHS and DVD sales and TV rights, it probably just about broke even. Very few films with a mid-range budget end up losing money.

Comment: @Valorum - Brilliant! Thank you. But I'd have sworn I've never seen the film! Must have been one hell of a night .......

Comment: @JohnBib - Traumatic experiences can often lead to memory loss.